# Using Gerrit to enforce linear history

Tags: git, rebase, gerrit, squash

I work on a large team and to help improve stability and ease of reverting we want to enforce **all topic branches to be rebased and squashed before merging** into our master branch.

The problem is that members of our team are uncomfortable with a rebase-like workflow.

Is using Gerrit a good way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with Gerrit, but arguably Gerrit isn't optimized for this workflow.

At $DAYJOB, we collaborate on topic branches, submit the commits when they are ready, and when the branch is ready to merge back into master, we first merge master into the topic branch.  Once the topic branch is up to date with master, we merge back from the topic branch into master.

The other option with a rebase workflow is to not submit the commits to the topic branch until everything is ready to go.  The commits need to live in code review for extended periods of time, and developers working on the topic branch need to check out from the Gerrit UI rather than from the published git server.

I've worked through this with some features on Gerrit itself, and it works OK, but not as smoothly as possible.  One example - imagine a series of commits `A - B - C`.  Developer 1 makes a change to `B` and uploads `A - B' - C`.  Around the same time, Developer 2 makes a change to `C` and uploads `A - B - C'`.  Developer 2 has just overwritten the change `B'` without knowing it.

With a merge workflow, this situation isn't possible because change `B` is already published and cannot be replaced (ignoring the force-push possibility).